# Jersey 2: render Swagger static content correctly without trailing slash(/)

Tags: javascript, html, url, swagger

What I did is to use `Grizzly`/`Jersey` to host `swagger-ui`, which is static content.

Here's part of `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:2.22.1'
compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-grizzly2-http:2.22.1'
compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-grizzly2-servlet:2.22.1'
```

Here's how to configure static content with `Grizzly`:

```
httpServer = GrizzlyWebContainerFactory.create(uri);
httpServer.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(new StaticHttpHandler("swagger-ui"), "/swagger");
```

`swagger-ui` is the folder under the project root folder.

**Everything is fine when I access `http://localhost/swagger/`** but when I try `http://localhost/swagger`, it only gives a simple page without rendering, which seems all css/js files are missing:
[image]

I'm wondering what's the best way to make url without trailing slash(/) to be the same as those with trailing slash.

Update:
I've raised a ticket to swagger-ui: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1966 but it said it's a configuration problem with `Grizzly` so another ticket for `Grizzly`: https://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY-1823

No solution found now. I'm thinking to use another web server.

Comment: will be fixed in Grizzly 2.3.25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that (as commented by alexey) this has since been fixed in a recent version of Grizzly.

You can either add this to your `pom.xml` or update the version number

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.grizzly</groupId>
    <artifactId>grizzly-http-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.28</version>
</dependency>
```

And Grizzly will automatically return a 301 redirect from the url without the trailing slash, to one with the trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you either want map to the HTML file swagger-ui.html or to serve up the jar you could try this [html server grizzly+jersey (.html from .jar archive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806312/html-server-grizzlyjersey-html-from-jar-archive)

UPDATE:

The issue is with the Grizzly routing. E.g. if you check your browser error log you'll see it's trying to load from http://localhost:18888/css/typography.css  not http://localhost:18888/swagger/css/typography.css.

I couldn't find any info about how Grizzly does routing and it seems to be inconsistent. E.g. http://localhost/swagger loads index.html fine, but not swagger-ui.js which both are on the same path. I've used other servers like Nginx to serve static files and haven't had any issue like us.

A workaround is to map each swagger-ui folder separately or you could deploy Swagger as a single JAR by using the [this](https://github.com/webjars/swagger-ui/blob/master/pom.xml) as I already said in the comments. I also looked at using wildcards as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25309244/wildcards-in-grizzly-httphandlers-mappings), but didn't have any luck.

```
    httpServer.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(new StaticHttpHandler("<basepath>/lib"),"/lib");
    httpServer.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(new StaticHttpHandler("<basepath>/css"),"/css");
...
```

Comment: could you elaborate how to map to HTML file swagger-ui.html?

Comment: Are you also hosting a dynamically generated Swagger doc? For example we host our docs and swagger ui using Springfox which takes care of the configuring the web server to host swagger ui see http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/snapshot/

Comment: Yes, I'll use `swagger` to export my restful api. But for `swagger ui`, I just use the static content downloaded from guihub

Comment: Did you look at Springfox? I would deploy Swagger UI using that unless you have some other requirement.

Comment: Not yet, I don't want to import `Springfox` into my project cause there's already a web container `Grizzly` for `swagger`. Everything is fine just want to make `/swagger` works as `/swagger/`

Comment: Got it. Last question - are you serving swagger-ui as a jar from this source https://github.com/webjars/swagger-ui? If not please post the link to the source code you want to host and I'll post the code to do it.

Comment: no. I serve `swagger-ui` as a folder (folder name: swagger-ui) under root folder. The content is from https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist